# Intellij idea settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

How can I set up an Intellij idea so that when writing a string and moving to a new line, the plus is put not at the end of the old line, but at the beginning of the new one (according to maven standards)?

I tried to find these settings in the code style but did not find(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [Wrapping and Braces](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html#wrapping_and_braces_tab) tab under Editor > Code Style: "Binary expressions > Operation sign on next line"

[image]